# Monitoring the connection of a paired bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have written the code which returns me a list of all the paired bluetooth devices of a android device.One among the list of paired bluetooth devices is my laptop as well.

Now my question is

Is there a way I can monitoring the bluetooth connectivity status between the laptop and the android device.The output which I need is "Connected" if there is a bluetooth connection present and "Disconnected" if there is no bluetooth connection

---

The android version is 2.1.Eclair

Before I proceed further , I have some questions.

->Should I test this application when I connect the laptop and device through USB?
->How to run it on a separate thread or from an AsyncTask?
->The above code is not working for me if I connect the device and the laptop through USB and then launch the application. Even though the laptop and the phone are nearby and they are paired, I am not able to see a connected status in the phone.

The code which I have written is as follows

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_);

    out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Getting the Bluetooth adapter
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    // out.append("\nAdapter: " + adapter);

    // Check for Bluetooth support in the first place
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if (adapter == null) {
        out.append("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");
        return;
    }

    // Starting the device discovery
    out.append("\nStarting discovery...");
    adapter.startDiscovery();
    out.append("\nDone with discovery...");

    // Listing paired devices
    out.append("\nDevices Pared:");
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
            .getBondedDevices();

    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
        out.append("\nFound device: " + device);
        out.append("\n The name is: " + device.getName());
        out.append("\n The type is: "
                + device.getBluetoothClass().getDeviceClass());

        Method m;
        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + device.getName());
            m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket",
                    new Class[] { int.class });
            BluetoothSocket socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            socket.connect();
            out.append("Connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.append("\nDisconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Which android version you are using?

You must have the permission on your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

You can try the code below, but be sure to run it on a separate thread or from an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or your UI can hang up.
This will check for your paired devices and try to connect to each one. If it is successful then it prints **Connected** on logcat or else it prints **Disconnected**.

```
private void checkPairedPrinters() throws IOException {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            Method m;
            try {
                System.out.println("Trying to connect to " + device.getName());
                m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
                BluetoothSocket socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
                socket.connect();
                System.out.println("Connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Disconnected");
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , I am already  have the permission in my AndroidManifest file .  in my case the connection will be between mobile devices How can i use this method in my code ? where i must call it?